# Access local variable in promise then scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope, promise, bind

I want to access a local variable `x` in the context of `then` using `bind` but all I get is `x` is undefined.
I am using `Promise` to retrieve data.

The ajax call happens with this function:

```
function ajaxCall(){
  p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:9090/bru/struc/arrivals',
      headers: { 'Authorization' : "Basic " + btoa("BRU:BRU")},
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        resolve(data)
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          xhr = reject
      }
    })
  })
}
```

And here I want to unwrap promise and assign its values to the local variable `x`

```
function getColumns(){
  var x
  r = ajaxCall().then(function(result){
    this.x.val = result \\result is available here, I can see it
    console.log(result)
  }.bind(this))
  console.log('Columns retrieved.')
  return x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with .`done` instead of .`then`

```
function getColumns(){
  var x
  r = ajaxCall().done(function(result){
    this.x.val = result \\result is available here, I can see it
    console.log(result)
  }.bind(this))
  console.log('Columns retrieved.')
  return x
}
```